# C/Java - Read 2 files write in one

Tags: c

I need help with subtitles =)

I have two .srt files with subtitles. One is in English and the other in Slovene. The problem is that the file in Slovene doesn't have the right
time code, so subtitles are quicker than actual line. What I want to do is to write a program that reads both files, take the number of subtitle and
the timecode from *eng.srt* file and the subtitles from *slo.srt* file and writes all that in *complete.srt*. I don't care about if its in Java or C.
I am currently trying to write the program in C and I would appriciate any help.

Now to demonstrate it what I want to do:

```
eng.srt (right timecode)

1
00:00:01,259 --> 00:00:03,734
<i>Previously on...</i>

2
00:00:03,746 --> 00:00:06,910
<i>Tom and Lynette drifted further apart,</i>

3
00:00:06,911 --> 00:00:09,275
<i>and Jane took advantage.</i>

4
00:00:09,440 --> 00:00:10,670
I'm scared.

5
00:00:10,671 --> 00:00:13,362
<i>Roy helped Karen face her cancer.</i>




slo.srt (right subtitles)

1
00:00:00,009 --> 00:00:02,484
<i>Prejšnič...</i>

2
00:00:02,496 --> 00:00:05,660
<i>Tom and Lynette
sta se še bolj odtujila,</i>

3
00:00:05,661 --> 00:00:08,025
<i>in Jane je to izkoristila.</i>

4
00:00:08,190 --> 00:00:09,420
Strah me je.

5
00:00:09,421 --> 00:00:12,112
<i>Roy se je pomagal Karen
soočiti z rakom.</i>



complete.srt (where i write)

1
00:00:01,259 --> 00:00:03,734
<i>Prejšnič...</i>

2
00:00:03,746 --> 00:00:06,910
<i>Tom and Lynette
sta se še bolj odtujila,</i>
...
```

This is what i have so far (i open 3 files, i will be updating my work as i go):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ch, sf1[20], sf2[20], tf[20];
   FILE *source1, *source2, *target;

   //first source file
   printf("Enter name of first source file\n");
   gets(sf1);

   source1 = fopen(sf1, "r");

   //seconds source file
   printf("Enter name of second source file\n");
   gets(sf2);

   source2 = fopen(sf2, "r");

   if( source == NULL )
   {
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   //target file
   printf("Enter name of target file\n");
   gets(tf);

   target = fopen(tf, "w");

   if( target == NULL )
   {
      fclose(source);
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }




   printf("File writen successfully.\n");

   fclose(source1);
   fclose(source2);
   fclose(target);

   return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to tell the program to read only the numbers from *eng.srt* file, and than skip the subtitle part and wait, than read the *slo.srt file* take out subtitles and skip the numbers.

Comment: Please carefullyy read the help section. This is not the place to simply ask for code. Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's a good practice to show a snippet of your code when asking a question on stack overflow

Comment: And what exactly is your problem/ question?

Answer (score 0):

This is easier done through pattern matching languages like awk. The patterns are pretty simple here. For time code, it starts with 2 digits (^[0-9][0-9]) and the subtitles start with  (^). I am not elaborating the solution since I don't know if you will be using one of those scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

The main logic is simple. Here is the `pseudo-code` for it.

```
for each subtitle in file1 and file2:
    extract_time_from_file1;
    extract_subtitle_from_file2;
    write_into_new_file_combining_the_time_and_string
```

Here is a completely working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
string read_title_string(ifstream& in)
{
    string ans="";
    string tmp;
    getline(in, tmp);//neglect the subtitle number
    getline(in, tmp);//neglect the time..
    /*sub-title extraction*/
    while(1)//read until the blank line and store all the strings..
    {
     getline(in, tmp);
     if(tmp.length()==0)
        break;
    ans += tmp;
    }
    return ans;
}
string read_title_time(ifstream& in)
{
    string ans="";
    string tmp;
    getline(in, tmp);//ignore subtitle number..
    getline(in, ans);//this is what we want..
    while(1)//read until a blank line and ignore them..
    {
        getline(in, tmp);
        if(tmp.length()==0)
            break;
    }
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream ins("slo.srt"),outs("eng.srt");
    ofstream ans("complete.srt");
    int count=1;
    while(!ins.eof() && !outs.eof())
    {
        ans<<count++<<endl;
        ans<<read_title_time(outs)<<endl;
        ans<<read_title_string(ins)<<endl;
        ans<<endl;
    }
    ins.close();outs.close();ans.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Note carefully that this code relies on the structure of the file. If the contents are organised in a different way, this may not work. Hope this helps!!

Comment: hmm, this code is not working for me. it launches great and doesnt report any errors, but it doesnt write anything in the complete.srt file. tried with only 3 subtitle lines

Comment: I relied on the structure of the subtitle file. If there is atleast one extra blank into it, It fails. try improving this code to get the exact output.